# How to I display video in left and right column in append without duplicating it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have video channel that I want to display all the the related video in that page. I displayed it from left to the right. But now I got problem with the same data appear twice left and right in one div. I know this is wrong but how do I corrected it ?

This is the current output that I got with my code
[image]

below is what I have tried

```js
onst display = (id) => {
  axios.get(`${url}category?=${id}`)
    .then(function(res) {
      if (res.data.status == 'success') {
        res.data.result.map((e) => {

          $("video1").append(`
                            <div class="nk-block">
                                    <div class="row g-gs">
                                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                                            <div class="card card-bordered h-100">
                                                <div class="card-inner">
                                                    <div class="align-end gy-3 gx-5 flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap flex-xl-wrap">
                                                        <div class="nk-sale-data-group flex-md-nowrap g-4">
                                                            <iframe width="430" height="300" src="${e.video}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="card-title-group align-start mb-2" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                                                        <div class="card-title" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><h6 class="title">${e.title}</h6></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                                            <div class="card card-bordered h-100">
                                                <div class="card-inner">
                                                    <div class="align-end gy-3 gx-5 flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap flex-xl-wrap">
                                                        <div class="nk-sale-data-group flex-md-nowrap g-4">
                                                             <iframe width="430" height="300" src="${e.video}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="card-title-group align-start mb-2" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                                                        <div class="card-title" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><h6 class="title"> ${e.title} </h6></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
                            </div>`);

        });
      }

    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="video1"></div>
```

How do I achieve output like this and prevent it form duplicating it ?

[image]

My main concern is how do I display different video on left and right column. With my current code, left and right column sit on in the same div. That's the reason why I think it produce the same output.

```
<div class="nk-block">
   <div class="row g-gs">
        //left column
        <div class="col-xl-6"></div>
         //right column
        <div class="col-xl-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

example of data inside my API

```
 "status": "success",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "title": "Tutorial 1",
            "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6NZfCO5SIk&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh"
        },
          {
            "id": 37,
            "title": "Tutorial 2",
            "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTB0EiLXUC8&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh"
        },
          {
            "id": 48,
            "title": "Tutorial 3",
            "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TnBZ8rom9c&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh"
           
        }
    ]
```

Comment: your querstion need more clearity like what url you are accessing what kind of data you are dealing with

Comment: @AmirRahman I'm using API to retrieve the video data, it just a simple data inside the API. My questions is more to how can I adjust the div class inside the append function. to make sure that different video sit on left and right column.

Comment: can you show url api example ?

Comment: @AmirRahman i have updated example of data inside my api

Comment: you need a better layout first as i can see you are appending two videos per row and your map function is giving 1 value at a time so its duplicating it, there are two possible solutions either change your layout to manage 2 items per row automatically with grid system or make a custom `for` loop to iterate two items at a time

Comment: yes that is exactly my problem. How do I do the the custom `for` loop in this append function ? what will be the example of the loop that i should custom ?

Comment: wait a min i am writing a loop then posting it

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to handle such situation thought i will not suggest to use this instead change your markup to one parent based and append all items in same level instead nesting 2 per row

**html**

```
<div id="video1" class="nk-block">

</div>
```

**js**

```
 <script>
 var exampleData = [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "title": "Tutorial 1",
            "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6NZfCO5SIk&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh"
        },
          {
            "id": 37,
            "title": "Tutorial 2",
            "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTB0EiLXUC8&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh"
        },
          {
            "id": 48,
            "title": "Tutorial 3",
            "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TnBZ8rom9c&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh"
        }
]

for(let i=0;i<exampleData.length;i+=2){
    let val1 = exampleData[i], val2 = typeof exampleData[i+1] != "undefined"?exampleData[i+1]:null

    $("#video1").append(`
            <div class="row g-gs">
                <div class="col-xl-6">
                    <div class="card card-bordered h-100">
                        <div class="card-inner">
                            <div class="align-end gy-3 gx-5 flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap flex-xl-wrap">
                                <div class="nk-sale-data-group flex-md-nowrap g-4">
                                    <iframe width="430" height="300" src="${val1.video}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-title-group align-start mb-2" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                                <div class="card-title" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><h6 class="title">${val1.title}</h6></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ${val2?`
                <div class="col-xl-6">
                    <div class="card card-bordered h-100">
                        <div class="card-inner">
                            <div class="align-end gy-3 gx-5 flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap flex-xl-wrap">
                                <div class="nk-sale-data-group flex-md-nowrap g-4">
                                    <iframe width="430" height="300" src="${val2.video}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-title-group align-start mb-2" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                                <div class="card-title" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><h6 class="title">${val2.title}</h6></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>        
                `:""}
            </div> 
    `);
}    
</script>
```

**suggested layout**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto); /*as many col per row*/
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>

<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>

<p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: "markup to one parent" meaning I have to display 1 per row ?

Comment: you didnt mentioned does this code resolves your problem ? and what i mean to say is use grid that will manage row col from parent element only take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: i have updated answer check suggested layout